# Can a google ad on a webpage scrape content from the current page?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, ads

- Can a google ad on a webpage access the html of the page?
- Can it inject scripts to the page?
- Does it matter if the page is served using https or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *Can a google ad on a webpage access the html of the page?*

   - The google code can. Like any JavaScript code on your page can. We may suppose that Google do not allow their advertisers to do something like that.
2. *Can it inject scripts to the page?*

   - Again, the JavaScript code can do it. Like you can write document.write and script tags... but let's suppose that Google will forbid their advertisers of doing so.
3. *Does it matter if it's https or not?*

   - No. That's on the protocol level, I suppose Google serves everything over TLS, anyway it does not matter.

**edit** What I mean is that the way the traffic is sent to the user computer (encrypted with TLS or not) does not affect what a script can or can't do... well in some browsers there may be restrictions when there is [mixed content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content)

Comment: Clarified the last question.

Comment: So a page with a ad and a login box on the same page, can theoretically have the login data stolen through the banner by collecting all data in all input fields.

Comment: Yes, theoretically it can bind to every keystroke and act as a key logger for sure.